# Can I compile and execute RenderScript on desktop(x86_64) like OpenCL/Cuda?

Tags: android, android-ndk, renderscript

I have a library for real-time image processing, written in C/C++ & OpenCL (originally for desktop). I've ported it into android recently. Here is what I've done:

- Build a shared object with NDK
- Create JNI and a simple Android app to use that shared object

The app can run successfully but the performance of OpenCL does not good as I expected. Some papers prove that RenderScript is faster than OpenCL (in certain cases), so is there any way that I can develop a few RenderScript kernels (with NDK) like OpenCL?

Thanks in advance.